# Centering Mdframe

Tags: mdframed

I found an example from a previous question on how to customize a text box using Mdframe. I'm having a tough time centering the box,

```
\documentclass[11.5pt]{report}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames] {xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\newlength{\MyMdframedWidthTweak}%
\NewEnviron{MyMdframed}[1][]{%
    \setlength{\MyMdframedWidthTweak}{\dimexpr%
        +\mdflength{innerleftmargin}
        +\mdflength{innerrightmargin}
        +\mdflength{leftmargin}
        +\mdflength{rightmargin}
        }%
    \savebox0{%
        \begin{varwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\MyMdframedWidthTweak\relax}%
            \BODY
        \end{varwidth}%
    }%
    \begin{mdframed}[
        backgroundcolor=lightgray, 
        shadow=true, 
        shadowsize=4pt,
        roundcorner=5pt,
        userdefinedwidth=\dimexpr\wd0+\MyMdframedWidthTweak\relax, 
        #1]
        \usebox0
    \end{mdframed}
}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\centering
\begin{minipage}[c]{5in}
\begin{MyMdframed}[backgroundcolor=blue!10]
    blah blah blah
\end{MyMdframed}
\end{minipage}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

which gives me the box, but it will only left align to the page. How can I freely adjust the alignment of the entire box?

Comment: Do you want the box centered?

Comment: Yes please. Centered with the left and right margins.

Comment: I figured it out. All I needed to do was add "align=center" next to my options for background color.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out myself. All I had to do was add "align=center" next to my options for background color. So

```
\begin{MyMdframed}[backgroundcolor=blue!10, align=center]
    blah blah blah
\end{MyMdframed}
```